# Error while counting nodes of binary search tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to write a function that counts the number of nodes of a binary search tree. However, I'm getting an error when I execute that function. This is the error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'right'. The error is for the line p=p.right.

Let me know if more data is to be provided.

Here is the function:

```
def countelements(self, root):
    stack=[]
    p=root
    count=0
    while p!=None:
        stack.append(p)
        p=p.left
        count=count+1
    while (len(stack)>0):
        p=stack.pop()
        p=p.right
        while p!=None:
            p=p.left
            stack.append(p)
            count=count+1
            
    return count
```

Comment: You're accessing p.right before you check if p is None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you work with recursive data structures, such as binary tree, you often want to use recursion.

```py
def count_elements(root):
    if root is not None:
        left = count_elements(root.left)
        right = count_elements(root.right)
        return left + right + 1  # +1 for root itself
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Recursion is a bit confusing for me and thus I try to use non-recursive methods. But thanks for the solution.

Comment: You are welcome. Basically, you call the same function with usually a bit different arguments. In this case, you first decides whether there is anything to count (root is not None) and if so, you first compute elements of the left subtree, then the right subtree. Eventually you sum up the results and add one for the root, which was not considered so far.

Comment: @Amit You should know that there are pros and cons of recursive vs iterative solutions. Each level of the tree will add an activation frame to the call stack, extremely deep (i.e. unbalanced) search trees could result in reaching the recursion depth limit for instance. Just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't thought through your core logic, but the source of the problem of why there is a `None` inside your stack must be the inner loop (See inline comment below).

```
        while p!=None:
            p=p.left # But what if p.left is None?
            stack.append(p)
            count=count+1
```

Comment: You hit the nail.